# How to use nested AND to check two rows values in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a table. I need to check whether the values will expire or not.

My conditions are

- If the number is repeating or not repeating in column A and contains value in Column C OR D. Then the expiry is NO.
- **If the number is repeating in column A and does not contains value in
  Column C OR D but contains value in all other Column C OR D. Then the expiry is NO.**
- If the number is repeating or not repeating in column A and does not contains value in Column C OR D. Then the expiry is Yes.

For eg: In my image, In column A 1001 is repeating (A4 & A5), but C4:D4 have no values and C5:D5 have values. So i need E4 and E5 values as NO

I used the formula below but it is not working. How can i change the formula. Help me

`=IF(AND(AND(COUNTIF(A:A;A2)>1); AND(C2="";D2="")); "Yes"; "No")`

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have too many AND() logicals: `=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A:A;A2)>1; AND(C2="";D2="")); "Yes"; "No")` Further, if it's Excel 2007 or later you can just list all the operands in a single AND(): `=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A:A;A2)>1; C2=""; D2=""); "Yes"; "No")`. Otherwise nest the if statements, it's just a little harder to read: `=IF(COUNTIF(A:A;A2)>1; IF(AND(C2="";D2=""); "Yes"; "No"); "No")`

Comment: OK. But i need the 2nd conditions to be satisfied in the formula. Do u have idea

Comment: might be able to help in my lunch break if it doesn't get picked up by someone before hand, won't have time to write up the formula / explanation now unfortunately... Usually a fast turn around in here so I doubt it'll still be open by lunch break.

Comment: Why have you included a VBA tag?

Comment: Do you mean "Previous" (E5 looks at rows 1-5) or "Other" (look at entire columns)?  If "Previous" then E4 and E5 are correct.  Also, the rules as you wrote them should mean that E**2** is "Yes", not "No" because C2 and D2 are empty.   Finally, try using `COUNTIFS` to check 2 conditions at once

Answer (score 1):

**N.B. The formula and screenshot posted do not match rule 2 as stated.**  If you are looking for a value *anywhere* in Columns C or D instead of just previous rows, then change any Ranges (`A1:$An` to `A:A`)

---

Using `COUNTIFS` will let you check multiple conditions as an `AND`.  (i.e. `COUNTIFS(A:A,1001,B:B,"C")` will count rows with Code 1001 `AND` Type "B")

You appear to want to check the current row and previous rows, so rather than `A:A` we will look in the range `A$1:An`, where *n* is the current row.  If *n*=2 (cell `E2`) then you want `A$1:A2`

This means we have 2 things to look for:

1) Rows where A$1:A*n* matches A*n* `AND` C$1:C*n* matches C*n*

`OR`

2) Rows where A$1:A*n* matches A*n* `AND` D$1:D*n* matches D*n*

We can write these as a pair of `COUNTIFS`s and add them together - this will mean that the row is counted twice if you have a number in both "Value 1" and "Value 2", but we don't care about the actual value (only if it is >0 or not)

(Formula is for cell E2)

`COUNTIFS(A$1:A2,A2,C$1:C2,"<>")+COUNTIFS(A$1:A2,A2,D$1:D2,"<>")`

So, if this is >0 then there is a row from 1 to *n* (currently 2) where Code = A*n* `AND` (Value 1 not blank `OR` Value 2 not blank)

`=IF((COUNTIFS(A$1:A2,A2,C$1:C2,"<>")+COUNTIFS(A$1:A2,A2,D$1:D2,"<>"))>0,"No","Yes")`

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A:A,A2) > 1,D2="",C2="",OR(D1<>"",C1<>"")),"NO",IF(OR(C2<>"",D2<>""),"NO","YES"))
```

It will return different result from the one you posted, as it's wrong. Also, review your logic, because you are thinking about it in wrong order, if you know what I mean :) Conditions should be checked in different order than you stated :) and `OR` operators should also be used.

Also, formula references to previous row, in first row you have none, so you should determine Expiry value by yourself.